# Why I'm not able to listen Recorded file Content

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am using Java Sound API to record audio through a microphone. The audio file is recorded and stored at the '/root/RecFiles/' location. But when I'm trying to play the recorded audio file, recorded voice is not coming out from the headphone/speakers.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class RecordingTest {
    static final long RECORD_TIME = 6000;

    File wavFile = new File("/root/RecFiles/RecordedFile.wav");

    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

    TargetDataLine line;

    AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 8000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int channels = 1;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean be= true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, be);
        return format;
    }

    void start() {
        try {
            AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                System.out.println("Line not supported");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);

            line.open(format);
            line.start();

            System.out.println("Start capturing...");

            AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

            System.out.println("Start recording");
            System.out.println("isline open : " + line.isOpen());
            System.out.println("isFileFOrmat support: " + AudioSystem.isFileTypeSupported(fileType));
            int recordResult = AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);
            System.out.println("writeResult : " + recordResult);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void finish() {
        line.stop();
        line.close();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final RecordingTest recorder = new RecordingTest();
        Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(RECORD_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.finish();
            }
        });
        stopper.start();
        recorder.start();
    }
}
```

After Executing the above code, The file at the location is like this:

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 78654 Jun 11 10:47 RecordedFile.wav

os : centos6

java version : 1.8

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you have only done a single write, and so have only the bare start of the recording stored. The return value `recordResult` will show the number of bytes recorded. How does it compare to an expected value, where there are 16000 bytes per second? (8000 fps x 2 bytes per frame)

The `write` command should be placed in a loop of some sort. A `while` loop with a `boolean` to signal when to stop is a common way to handle recordings.

Comment: I verified the same code is working fine in my Windows Machine. Can anyone help me, please... Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us the return value received in "recordResult" on both systems? I'd like to verify that they are the same. Can you also verify if your start() method loops or not? One possibility to check for is if the default buffer size for your reads are the same in the two systems. No guarantee that they are, afaik.

Comment: Hi @Phil Freihofner, After doing so much R&D on this got to know If Client and server are on the same machine working fine else on client machine microphone what we spoke that voice is not recorded in that file.